# Can I force the minions to attack me, when no enemy chamion is around?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that you can get minion "aggro" when you attack an enemy champion or when nothing else is around.

But how do I force them to attack me, when no enemy champion is around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing you can do far from facing them without your minions or taunting them, since they have more priority facing minions when champs don't autoattack each other.

[From the lol wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Minion#Behavior):

> Minions prioritize targets in the following order:
>
> - An enemy champion designated by a call for help from an allied champion. (Enemy champion attacking an Allied champion)
> - An enemy minion designated by a call for help from an allied champion. (Enemy minion attacking an Allied champion)
> - **An enemy minion designated by a call for help from an allied minion. (Enemy minion attacking an Allied minion)**
> - An enemy turret designated by a call for help from an allied minion. (Enemy turret attacking an Allied minion)
> - **An enemy champion designated by a call for help from an allied minion. (Enemy champion attacking an Allied minion)**
> - The closest enemy minion.
> - **The closest enemy champion.**

Comment: Additionally, you could Taunt them, I think the only taunt that affects minions anymore is Idol of Durand (Galio Ultimate) though. Raummus's Punctuating Taunt works on monsters but I don't think that it works on minions (not certain).

Comment: I read someplace there *used* to be a method of attracting aggro by right-clicking on an enemy champ who was elsewhere on the map (but visible). This was quite a while ago, though.

Comment: @Shelby115 You can no longer target minions with taunt as rammus.

Comment: @dphil Yeah, it's probably for the best too, I used to taunt minions by mistake all the time.